# Laravel Eloquent: Get Relations Dynamically

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I am trying to create a livewire component to create a table dynamically. I am now stuck when it comes to adding a relationship to another table.

As an example I have 3 tables:-

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `class_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `section_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `classes` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `sections` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Livewire Datatable Component:-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Datatable extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $model;
    public $columns;
    public $query;

    public function mount($model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->columns = $this->columns();
    }

    public function builder()
    {
        return new $this->model;
    }

    public function columns()
    {
        $row = $this->builder()->firstOrFail();

        return collect(array_keys($row->getAttributes()))
            ->reject(function ($column) use ($row) {
                return in_array($column, $row->getHidden());
            }
        );
    }

    public function records()
    {
        return $this->builder()->paginate(10);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.datatable');
    }
}
```

Livewire View:

```
<div>
    <div class='overflow-x-auto w-full'>
        <table class="w-full">
            <thead class="bg-gray-200">
                <tr class="text-left text-sm text-gray-500">
                    <th></th>
                    @foreach ($columns as $column)
                        <th class="p-2">{{ Str::replace('_', ' ', Str::title($column)) }}</th>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
                @foreach ($this->records() as $record)
                    <tr class="hover:bg-gray-200">
                        <td class="p-2 w-4">
                            <div class="flex items-center">
                                <input type="checkbox"
                                    wire:model="checked"
                                    value="{{ $record->id }}"
                                    class="bg-gray-50 border-gray-300 focus:ring-3 focus:ring-sky-200 h-4 w-4 rounded">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        @foreach ($columns as $column)
                            <td class="p-2 whitespace-nowrap text-base font-medium text-gray-900">
                                {{ $record->{$column} }}
                            </td>
                        @endforeach
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Blade View:

```
<livewire:datatable model="App\Models\Student" />
```

Current Output

| id | name | class id | section id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Chris | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | Bob | 2 | 2 |

Desired Output

| id | name | class | section |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Chris | class 1 | section 1 |
| 2 | Bob | class 2 | section 2 |

How can I replace class_id and section_id with class.name and section.name, without hard coding it in as the idea is this can be used on any table by simply changing the initial model when calling the component?

Comment: Please check this link, You can simply do thing using relation and also you can change label name. 
https://livewire-datatables.com/relation

Comment: I've had a look at this package and it looks great, exactly what I'm trying to do so I might use it if I can't resolve this in my own version.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function builder()
{
    return User::query()
        ->leftJoin('planets', 'planets.id', 'users.planet_id')
        ->leftJoin('moons', 'moons.id', 'planets.moon_id')
        ->groupBy('users.id');
}

public function columns()
{
    return [
        NumberColumn::name('id')
            ->filterable(),

        Column::name('planets.name')
            ->label('Planet')
}
```

https://github.com/MedicOneSystems/livewire-datatables#custom-column-names

Comment: this relies on specifying the model, tables and columns whereas I would like this to be dynamic.